# Override paint without extending JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

Is it possible to override the paint method, or draw onto a JFrame with a Graphics object without extending JFrame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You should extend JPanel or JComponent and override the `paintComponent(...)` and then add that component to the JFrame's contentPane. Leave JFrame's `paint(...)` method alone, and in fact you would only rarely (if ever) want to extend JFrame anyway.

Comment: @matheszabi: Thanks for the up vote, but please elaborate on your comment.

Comment: The content panel will override only the content of the JFrame, but if you want to override something else too, than not always you can. Eg. Title bar and so on. In most cases will work in others need to add more trick.

Comment: @mathes: I'll grant that you're right. Thanks for the clarification.